# CharSequence[ ] : Cant add element to array

Tags: java, android

```
CharSequence[] mPhotoOptions = new CharSequence[10];
               mPhotoOptions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.save_coupon_add_photo_options);

               if (!TextUtils.isEmpty( mItemList.mItemImagePath ) || !TextUtils.isEmpty( mResizedPhotoFilePath )  ) {
                   mPhotoOptions[2]= getResources().getString(R.string.remove_image);
               }
```

it gives `ArrayOutOfBoundException`

Answer (score 2):

You declare and allocate an array of 10 CharSequence in the 1st line of code, but it gets replaced in the 2nd line of code by an array of undetermined length, presumably less than what you expect.

(in response to OP followup)

To add an element, you'd have to create a new array and copy over the old results.  That's Java for you.  (Can you use an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)  instead???)  Using hard coded numbers for the size and index (which you probably shouldn't)

```
CharSequence[] newPhotoOptions = Arrays.copyOf(mPhotoOptions, 10);  // or old length +1
newPhotoOptions[2] = thatNewValue;  // or old length
```

(note - some old versions of Android do not have Arrays.copyOf() so you may want to use System.arraycopy() instead.)

Comment: It's not allocating 10 chars - it's allocating an array of 10 `CharSequence` elements. Those aren't chars.

Comment: "R.array.save_coupon_add_photo_options" refer to string array with 2 elements..And lenght of  "mPhotoOptions"(CharSequence[]) get fixed to 2..How can I add Third element..The above code give Exception.